# If and else statements in easyGUI?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, msgbox, easygui

So i have a basic question: how to use if and else statements correctly with easyGUI?
This is what I have:

```
import easygui

msg = "Oh i see m9, choos your difficulty"
title = "Mountain Dew Franchise"
choices = ["Pro 360 noscoper(+1001)", "Dank skrubl0rd(-666)"]
choice = easygui.ynbox(msg, title, choices)

#if choices==choices[0]:
    easygui.msgbox("Good choos m20, let the skrubl0rd noscoping begin.")

#if choices==choices[1]:
    easygui.msgbox("Oh i see m8.")
```

The # lines seem to be the problem area

It does not let me go to either msgbox, but instead just closes the program, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The if statement does not work any differently when using easygui than anywhere else. It's the values you're checking you should be worried about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
choice = easygui.ynbox(msg, title, choices)
```

This [ynbox](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html#ynbox) returns `True` or `False`. That means that `choice` can only be one of these two values.

```
if choices==choices[0]:
```

You are comparing if your list (`choices`) is equal to the value of your first element in the same list.

---

To make your program work, you need to modify your `if` section a bit.

```
if choice:
     easygui.msgbox("Good choos m20, let the skrubl0rd noscoping begin.")
else:
     easygui.msgbox("Oh i see m8.")
```

Since `choice` can only be `True` or `False` and the first option in your `choices` list become the `True` value, this logic will work.

Answer (score 1):

The `ynbox` returns `True` or `False`, not one of your `choices` (that's just what it displays on the two buttons!).  So, change your checks to `if choice:` and `else:` (and make sure your indentation's correct -- looks weird in your Q!-) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Example it may helpful:

```
from easygui import *


msg  = "Flavor"
title = "survey"
choices = ["vanila", "chocolate", "foo","strbry"]
choice = choicebox(msg, title, choices)

if choice == "foo":
   print "your choice is good" 
else:
   print "Try again its not a good choice !"
```